# Where does chrome store media contents of open source media formats like Blip.tv in your hard disk?

Tags: html5-video

How can I find where is the blip.tv storing its media in my hard disk ?

If it  is flash , I can track it using the fd used by the flash player process .

Can anyone tell me this ?

Chrome uses /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libtotem-cone-plugin.so for ogv , but I can see any such process open .

Somebody atleast tell me what process blip.tv like sites open when you open their videos so I can check the proc directory of the same .